# Is this character a member of House Baratheon?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I'm compiling a database of every named character in A Song of Ice and Fire. In *A Clash Of Kings*, Page 7 (Cressen's chapter,) he talks about:

> ...old **Ser Harbert**, the castellan of Storm's End in those years.

No mention is made of Ser Harbert's last name - it's not clear at this point if he is a Baratheon. His [wiki page](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Harbert) at A Wiki of Ice and Fire doesn't state his family name. But then on Page 148 (Davos' chapter), Stannis says:

> One day our [*Stannis'*] great uncle **Ser Harbert** told me to try a different bird

So Ser Harbert - presumably the same as the castellan of Storm's End - is Stannis' great-uncle. I would have inferred from this that his last name is Baratheon. Have I made a mistake here? Is there any possible way that a great-uncle could have a different last name, or does this confirm that Ser Harbert is a Baratheon? This question is more general genealogy than ASOIAF-specific, but it made more sense to put it on scifi.

Comment: You should note that even if he is a Baratheon, he wouldn't have a claim to the Iron Throne on that basis (except for the claim that comes from having the biggest warhammer). Robert's claim was based on his Targaryen ancestry, which Ser Harbert would not share.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well if you look at the Appendix of the book, you won't see him at the Baratheon family tree. So, he either isn't one, or is a (really) insignificant one.

A great uncle could have been from Stannis's mother's side. This means that he doesn't have 'Baratheon' as a last name. We can't know for sure, since Martin hasn't specified this

The same is stated at the [Wiki of Ice and Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Harbert); his family name is not know.

Comment: Pipped at the post by Shevliaskovic... Again! :) +1

Comment: The families of Westeros are *huge*, I wouldn't expect GRRM to list every Baratheon even three generations back. I've already checked AWOIAF, and they don't know his last name. I'm asking my inference that Ser Harbert is a Baratheon based on being Stannis' great-uncle, is correct.

Comment: @LeoKing even if he is, he must be a really distant one. If he was not, he would have been listed in the appendix of the book. That's why I said he might be an insignificant one

Comment: I'm not sure you've understood the question.

Comment: Ah, okay, that's what I was looking for, thanks. If you include that in the answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 3):

Steffon's father, lord Ormund Baratheon had a sister. She was supposed to marry a Targaryen but the prince fell in love and married at his own will. This made Lyonel, father of Ormund rebel and become Storm King. Later, Rhaenys became Ormund's wife to make peace. But what about Ormund's sister? I'm guessing she marries ser Harbert. It is common for Lords to marry their daughters to Knights who are trusted by the family.

Comment: So, he is a "great uncle" but it could simply be because he married a great aunt who *was* a Baratheon.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers given above (all viable), it's also possible that Ser Harbert was a bastard child of Lyonel Baratheon. Bastard knights are not unheard of in Westeros, and a bastard knight of a great lord being made castellan seems to be about the right level of social climbing.